# LINQ to Object Basic

Tags: c#, linq

I have following codes (I am a beginner);

```
string myVar = "abcd";
var myQuery = from x in myVar select x;     
MessageBox.Show( string.Join("\n", myQuery));
```

I'd like to have the result like this;

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Some hints please.

Thanks.

Comment: Jason,  Is this a school work / homework issue?  If so, I'd like to recommend that you first do it without linq, so that you understand what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @Joe ..Thanks for good tip. I can handle it without LINQ. Now I'm at chap 8 "LINQ" of Albabari brothers. (I found the second argument at Pg.385 but it lacks "it is Fluent-syntax only").

Comment: "Local query" means Fluent syntax ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) operator overload which accepts index of item. (unfortunately it's not available in query syntax):

```
String.Concat(myVar.Select((ch,i) => $"{i + 1} {ch}\n"))
```

Update: @Mattew correctly noticed that this code will add extra `\n` at the end. If it's not good, then you should use `String.Join` instead. Also consider to use [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) thus for windows platform new line string is `\r\n`:

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, myVar.Select((ch,i) => $"{i + 1} {ch}"))
```

Comment: Wow. so simple. Second argument... OK. I will check it out right now. Thanks.

Comment: I added number 1  "(i + 1)". Works like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: As a note this would add an extra line fee at the end compared to OPs example.

Comment: @MatthewWhited nice catch, then `String.Join` is better here. I just tried to make code more compact. Thanks)

Comment: `string.Join("\n", myVar.Select((ch,i) => $"{i + 1} {ch}"))` would resolve the extra line fee (if it matters ;)

Comment: @Jason if the answer helped you mark is as correct !

Comment: So, Is it Fluent-syntex only ? var myQuery = from x in myVar select ( (x, i ) =>  i + x ); I have type error. any help ?

Comment: @Jason yes it is, only methods (fluent) syntax. Query syntax supports only operators with singe argument